# Super User does not detect links which use internationalized domain names

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, unicode

In my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/193931/how-do-people-type-different-languages-into-computer/193959#193959), I was explaining about [Internationalized country code top-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domain). Unfortunately, standard links for some reason do not allow users to click on such links.

Such addresses are valid, so I believe that this is a bug which needs to be fixed.

Link to question on SO meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/).
Related SO meta question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41644/).

Comment: This probably affects the entire stack family and should probably be asked on http://meta.stackoverflow.com And it'll get more attention there.

Comment: @Nifle I'll ask it there. It seems to be by design.

Comment: @Sathya♦ Why does this have `status-completed` tag when the offered solution doesn't work in two of the top three browsers?

Comment: @AndrejaKo I've tried it in IE9, Firefox & Chrome adding a link to just the domain w/o http works fine http://i.imgur.com/7JEUz.png

Comment: @Sathya♦ OK, I believe you. It could be a problem on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the links via the Insert Hyperlink option present on the toolbar, the links will be converted to [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) & URL encoded.

Example:

- [президент.рф](http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84)

---

[image]