# How to link to URLs contaning strange unicode chars

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, unicode

In my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/238004/are-these-partitions-properly-aligned) I wanted to link to

**http://ldn.linuxfoundation.org/blog-entry/aligning-filesystems-ssd’s-erase-block-size**

and it didn't work. Note that the link as displayed here

http://ldn.linuxfoundation.org/blog-entry/aligning-filesystems-ssd’s-erase-block-size

ends before the apostrophe. Note that the apostrophe is not \u0027 so I can't replace it with %27. I don't know how to escape unicode in URLs in general, and I don't think I should have to. Markdown works normally very well, so it should be able to handle this, too, shouldn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Super User does not detect links which use internationalized domain names.](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1514/super-user-does-not-detect-links-which-use-internationalized-domain-names)

Comment: Note to those considering voting to close as a dup of  [1514](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1514/super-user-does-not-detect-links-which-use-internationalized-domain-names): These questions are not really related. 1514 deals with Unicode in the hostname part of an HTTP URL. This question is about Unicode in the path part of an HTTP URL. They are handled differently. The former uses punycode, while the later is less standardized, but usually uses percent encoded UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround, consider using a URL shortener such as [bit.ly](http://bit.ly)

Comment: Aren't there legal/censoring issues with libyan domain names?

Comment: None that I am aware of @DanielBeck

Comment: I checked -- it was a URL shortening service that specifically allowed linking to NSFW content. This likely won't be an issue on SuperUser.

Comment: I would not use an URL shortener in this trivial case.. if it's a Wolfram Alpha *crazy ass URL* then maybe, but not for a single `'`

Comment: Actually, the bit shortener is the only universal solution, that's why I accept this answer. The other is nicer and solves my problem as well, I know. But I'm not going to search for a different solution in case somebody makes a URL "fancy" in another way.

Answer (score 8):

If you still wonder how to do it... [**This one works!**](http://ldn.linuxfoundation.org/blog-entry/aligning-filesystems-ssd%E2%80%99s-erase-block-size)

It uses: %E2%80%99

Tool used: [Meyer Web - Eric - Tools - URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

See also: [Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)